# remove duplicates from an unsorted array in java

Tags: arrays

I was asked in one of the interview that i recently appeared to remove duplicates from unsorted array while still maintaining the order in which they appeared.

For example:

- Input: `int[] nums = [2,1,3,3,2,1,4]`
- Output shud be `int[] result = [2,1,3,4]`

I tried two options one with Hashset and other with list. But i was still wondering if there is an better optimized solution to this.
Appreciate if you can help me out
NerdyHB

Here is are solution

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums = new int[] { 2, 1, 3, 2, 1 };
    List<Integer> result = removeDuplicates(nums);
    System.out.println(result);

    int[] res = removeDuplicatesUsingHashSet(nums);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
}

public static List<Integer> removeDuplicates(int[] nums) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int n : nums) {
        if (!result.contains(n)) {
            result.add(n);
        }

    }
    return result;
}


public static int[] removeDuplicatesUsingHashSet(int[] nums) {
    HashSet<Integer> hset = new HashSet<>();
    for (int n : nums) {
        hset.add(n);
    }
    int[] result = new int[hset.size()];
    int counter = 0;
    Iterator<Integer> itr = hset.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        result[counter++] = itr.next();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: your HashSet solution doesn't preserve order.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

```
HashSet<Integer> hset = new HashSet<>();
```

to:

```
LinkedHashSet<Integer> hset = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main
{
public static void main (String[]args)
{
int[] arr = { 25, 14, 56, 15, 36, 36, 77, 18, 18, 49 };
int size=arr.length;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
  for(int j=i+1;j<size;j++)
  {
    if(arr[i]==arr[j])
    {
      arr[j]=arr[size-1];
      size--;
    }
 }
  }

 for(int a=0;a<size;a++)
  {
  System.out.print(arr[a]+" ");
  }

 }

}
```